# C++ GetAsyncKeyState doesnt always work any other methods to get a mouseclick?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, get, key, state

So as I said in the title GetAsyncKeyState doesnt  work. In my project im doing something that detects when the left mouse button is pressed then detected when it is unpressed.
Somtimesit detects the press but it mainly doesnt.
Here is my code:

````
       if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 1) {
           LBdown = true;
       }
       else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) == 0) {
           LBdown = false;
       }
   }```
````

Comment: [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) does **not** use the least-significant bit of the return value to report whether the button is currently up or down. Your expectations don't match the function's documented behavior.

Comment: Just get rid of the 2nd call in your `else`, you don't need it: `if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 1) { LBdown = true; } else { LBdown = false; }` which can be simplified to `LBdown = (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 1);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Would you be able to recommend something that does what im looking for?

Comment: `if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0) { /* the button is down */ } else { /* the button is up */ }`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you so much. You have saved me